# How to make a Makefile for a program for Haskell Language?

Tags: haskell, makefile, ghci

i'm new in Haskell language and i want to create a makefile for a haskell program that i'm working on it right now. But i'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you :)

Comment: We know what you want. Great. What you have so far?

Comment: I don't recommend that. Rather, use `ghc --make`, or `cabal`, or `stack`. If you do need `make`, read the docs about it: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/separate_compilation.html#using-make

Comment: Well you first think what commands you call yourself when making the program, and then turn that into a Makefile.

Comment: If your program was in `C` you'd use `gcc -c`, most Haskell programs are compiled with ghc so you use `ghc -c`.  If you want optimization then in C you'd use `-O2` or 3, with ghc you also use `-O2`.  If you want warnings in  C you use `-Wall`, with ghc it's `-Wall`. If you want to compile a binary with c you just drop the flag and call `gcc` while with Haskell you just drop the flag and use `ghc`.  If you want to link a program from many object files with C you can use the compiler or linker such as `gcc obj1.o obj2.o -o res`; with ghc you would call ghc `ghc obj1.o obj2.o -o res`. Questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost no Haskell project uses a Makefile, because that's clunky, hard to read and error-prone.

For simple one-off projects, you don't really need any dedicated build system at all: GHC can itself figure out the dependency between modules:

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ cat >> Hello.hs
module Main where

import Greeting

main = putStrLn greeting
```

---

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ cat >> Greeting.hs
module Greeting where

greeting = "Hello, World!"
```

---

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ ghc Hello.hs 
[1 of 2] Compiling Greeting         ( Greeting.hs, Greeting.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Hello.hs, Hello.o )
Linking Hello ...
```

---

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ ./Hello 
Hello, World!
```

...or simply

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ runhaskell Hello.hs
Hello, World!
```

For more involved projects and definitely for libraries, you want to use [Cabal](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/). I.e. you need a `.cabal` file, e.g. for the above “project” `hello.cabal`. Such a file can be generated semi-automatically by the `cabal` tool:

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ mkdir hello
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ mv Hello.hs hello
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ mv Greeting.hs hello
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp$ cd hello/
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp/hello$ cabal init
Package name? hello
This package name is already used by another package on hackage. Do you want to choose a different name? [default: y] n
Package version? [default: 0.1.0.0] 
Please choose a license:
   1) GPL-2
   2) GPL-3
   3) LGPL-2.1
   4) LGPL-3
   5) AGPL-3
   6) BSD2
 * 7) BSD3
   8) MIT
   9) ISC
  10) MPL-2.0
  11) Apache-2.0
  12) PublicDomain
  13) AllRightsReserved
  14) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: BSD3] 12
Author name? [default: Justus Sagemüller] 
Maintainer email? [default: sagemueller@geo.uni-koeln.de] 
Project homepage URL? 
Project synopsis? hello
Project category:
 * 1) (none)
   2) Codec
   3) Concurrency
   4) Control
   5) Data
   6) Database
   7) Development
   8) Distribution
   9) Game
  10) Graphics
  11) Language
  12) Math
  13) Network
  14) Sound
  15) System
  16) Testing
  17) Text
  18) Web
  19) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: (none)] 17
What does the package build:
   1) Library
   2) Executable
Your choice? 2
What is the main module of the executable:
 * 1) Main.hs (does not yet exist, but will be created)
   2) Main.lhs (does not yet exist, but will be created)
   3) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: Main.hs (does not yet exist, but will be created)] 3
Please specify? Hello.hs
Source directory:
 * 1) (none)
   2) src
   3) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: (none)] 
What base language is the package written in:
 * 1) Haskell2010
   2) Haskell98
   3) Other (specify)
Your choice? [default: Haskell2010] 
Add informative comments to each field in the cabal file (y/n)? [default: n] 

Guessing dependencies...
Generating Setup.hs...
Generating ChangeLog.md...
Generating hello.cabal...

You may want to edit the .cabal file and add a Description field.
```

The file will at this point contain:

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp/hello$ cat hello.cabal 
-- Initial hello.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further documentation,
--  see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/

name:                hello
version:             0.1.0.0
synopsis:            hello
-- description:         
license:             PublicDomain
author:              Justus Sagemüller
maintainer:          sagemueller@geo.uni-koeln.de
category:            Text
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  ChangeLog.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

executable hello
  main-is:             Hello.hs
  -- other-modules:       
  -- other-extensions:    
  build-depends:       base >=4.10 && <4.11
  -- hs-source-dirs:      
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

That's not quite complete, you still need to add `Greeting.hs` to the project: (without the filename extension)

```
...
executable hello
  main-is:             Hello.hs
  other-modules:       Greeting
  -- other-extensions:
...
```

But that's it, you can now do

```
sagemuej@sagemuej-X302LA:/tmp/hello$ cabal build
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring hello-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'hello' for hello-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'hello' for hello-0.1.0.0..
[1 of 2] Compiling Greeting         ( Greeting.hs, dist/build/hello/hello-tmp/Greeting.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Hello.hs, dist/build/hello/hello-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/hello/hello ...
```

Or, to just run the script, `cabal run`, or `cabal install` to make it always available on your system.